# Promoting site on MOOC

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Currently, it seems like there are too few questions asked on the site [image]

So it seems like the site should be promoted (unless all that can be asked has been answered).

Given the rising popularity of "massive on-line open courses" (MOOC), perhaps we could promote the course in this context (for example this course,  [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/course/exphys)). Promoting could be through participation & relevant linking or a more formal collaboration.

Comment: Any MOOCs you have in mind? The Human Physiology one perhaps?

Comment: Yes, the "Exercise Physiology: Understanding the Athlete Within" or similar at other sites

Comment: Ah, I hadn't joined that one yet. Yes, that looks like a great fit

Comment: https://www.coursera.org/course/nutritionforhealth one more course on Coursera

Comment: Nutrition and health seems to be good